# Can anyone help with fixing the touch pad on my Chromebook?

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, chromebook

For the record I have installed Xubuntu, through Chrubuntu, on my Toshiba C35 Chromebook. I knew coming in that there would be some hardware issues, and for the most part, I got the other issues fixed except for the touch pad; it doesn't work whatsoever, and I'm currently using a USB mouse for the time being.

So far I've tried the fixes from 
http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/1rsxkd/list_of_fixes_for_xubuntu_1310_on_the_acer_c720/[1][1]

I kept looking for solutions, and I kept coming across that it has something to do with a old/new kernel? I'm still a novice with understanding Linux in general, so I'm not sure what that meant. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I was already told to go to this link ( https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_C720_Chromebook#Touchpad_Kernel_Modules ), but it has offered no help either even with those instructions.

Comment: I'm working on porting the ChromeOS touchpad drivers to Ubuntu. Once I get them finished, I'll ping you with a link. Other than doing it yourself, I don't know of any other way to get it to work.